# Why is NGINX running slow with php_fpm fastcgi_cache enabled using wordpress?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fastcgi, slow-connection

I am having a little trouble. I followed the tutorials step by step at [rtcamp.com](http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx-wordpress-multisite-subdomains-fastcgi-cache-conditional-purging-domain-mapping/) for wordpress multisite, only changing the ‘example.com’ to my domain name. I have the nginx helper plugin installed and it looks like the whole site and everything works great. (It’s a network of about 40 sites moved from a LAMP setup)

I’m having an issue though. Even with the configuration using the fastcgi_cache, my page load time is extremely high.
This is what it reads when I view the source code timestamp:

```
<!--Cached using Nginx-Helper on 2013-03-12 00:21:19. It took 62 queries executed in 13.000 seconds.
Visit http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/faq/ for more details -->
```

This doesn't happen with the root site, only with the sub-directory sites.

Here are my configs:
This is the sites-available/example.com

```
#move next 3 lines to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf if you want to use fastcgi_cache across many sites 
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:500m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;

server {
    #@DM - uncomment following line for domain mapping or you will need to add every mapped-domain to server_name list 
    #listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com *.example.com ;
    #@DM - uncomment following line for domain mapping
    #server_name_in_redirect off;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #fastcgi_cache start
    set $skip_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }   

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
                rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
                rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*.php)$ $1 last;
        }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }    

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php; 
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

        fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  60m;
    }

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }   

    location ~* ^.+.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
#   location ~ /. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

##SITEMAP ABILTIES
    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

}
```

And my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ## Block spammers and other unwanted visitors  ##
    include blockips.conf;


    #FastCGI
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;



    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Help with this problem would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you establish is slow ?
Did you enable any sort of limits into php-fpm ?
Send the log files from php-fpm and nginx.

Comment: Well I consider it slow because it's taking upward of 13 seconds to load the page. I haven't changed anything in the php-fpm settings. I'm still learning this part of everything, and the tutorial I used didn't mention any changes to the php-fpm config. What sort of changes can I make?
Here is the php5-fpm.log:

Comment: Here is the php5-fpm.log:
`[12-Mar-2013 02:40:30] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 15715
[12-Mar-2013 02:40:30] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[12-Mar-2013 02:53:05] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[12-Mar-2013 03:06:22] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[12-Mar-2013 03:06:22] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!`

Comment: And there are several entries like this in the Nginx error log:
`2013/03/12 02:46:27 [error] 15735#0: *4804 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 102.94.37.89, server: example.com, request: "POST /toysandgames/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1363070786.9193959236145019531250 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"`

Comment: And in the nginx access log there are LOTS of these:
`174.129.102.11 - - [12/Mar/2013:23:02:35 -0400] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"`
However I have that ip address blocked in iptables... so I thought, I'll double check that.

Answer (score 1):

limit_req_zone limits requests to the server to one request per sec in `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;`, that includes PHP and static files requests depending on where you placed the `limit_req zone=one;` statement. Try to limit only PHP requests (`inside location ~ \.php$ {`)  and leave static content unrestricted.

Comment: nginx official document mentioned its better place inside the `http` block